# To find class K infinity bounds on given radially unbounded function

Tags: differential, positive-definite, bounded-variation, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let $f = x_1^2 + x_2^4$. How to find class $\mathcal{K_{\infty}}$ functions $\alpha_1(||x||)$ and $\alpha_2(||x||)$, such that,

$\alpha_1(||x||) \leq f \leq \alpha_2(||x||), \forall x \in {R}^2.$

$\textbf{Edit:}$

I have been following the nonlinear system analysis book by Khalil. According to the proof (Appendix C.4). One first needs to find,

$\phi(s) = \underset{s\leq ||x|| \leq r}{\text{inf}} f(x) \text{ for } 0\leq s\leq r.$

Then one can define $\alpha_1(s) \leq k\phi(s)$ with $0<k<1$.

But I am not able to understand how to find such $\phi(s)$ for given $f(s)$? I think there should a methodology to go about these types of questions. I would be grateful if someone helps me understand this.

Comment: Try to see if you can obtain something by writing $f= x_1^2+x_2^2-x_2^2+x_2^4=||x||^2+x_2^2(x_2^2-1) $

Comment: Anything you might have tried should go in the post. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @EDX I am not sure, how that can be used to address the issue. But that you for the reply.

Comment: @MicahWindsor, I have edited the question, please let me know if you can help.

Comment: The proofs involves polar coordinates. Try to do it and find a new $f$ expressed in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: I will develop it and see if I find a proof